# How far do we extend "all aspects of producing and consuming coffee"?

Tags: discussion

[Which books do you recommend to read for people who are interested in coffee?](https://coffee.stackexchange.com/questions/2772/which-books-do-you-advice-to-read-for-people-who-are-related-to-coffee)

This question asks for literature about coffee - is that still within our scope? My gut feeling would be *no*, yet our sadly generic [on-topic] gives no hint whatsoever.

Obviously I can (and did) VTC as too broad, but would this post have the potential of a fun Comunity Wiki? Like most language sites have a collection of sources? So answers would have to be in some kind of order, e.g. history, cultivation, roasting and brewing....

Answer (score 3):

As the one who asked the question, I also share the same feeling. Thus, I tried to specifically  mention "quality articles and joyful books" in the question text.

I hope with this note the question may end up well and we may share a nice collection of books to follow.

Just before posting the question, I checked the Coffee SE's tour page. It's noted as: "all aspects of producing and consuming coffee". So, the books are at the gray area to me. They may be either included in this definition or not. Both seems acceptable.

*One more idea:* Actually, I think I implied this in the question text, but it may be better to explicitly state that the question is asked to compile a **Coffee SE user reviewed and advised list of books with a possibility of form a community wiki page**.

Comment: I very much agree with the Comunity Wiki aspect.

Comment: @Stephie I will add this to the text of the question in bold, then.

Answer (score 3):

This question strikes me as very, very broad, quite fluid, and highly opinion-based. As new books come out, answers will inevitably change to the point that there cannot be any reasonable canonical answer.

I don't know whether community wiki or perhaps putting related books in the tag wiki for specific topics make the best approach here.

Answer (score 1):

On MathSE there are some very broad questions which--as you suggest--were fun and well-received. Why not?

Especially on this site, with its relatively small membership, the likelihood of a deluge is slight. I think if answers self-identify according to category that is sufficient order unless there are too many answers.